# How to write unit test cases for the DataStore saving and fetching method

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, datastore

I'm using dataStore preferences to store boolean value locally and uable to store it. I would like to write the unit test cases for dataStore implementation functions.

Below are the methods that I have created for saving and fetching the value. can someone help here how to write unit test cases for TestDataSourceImpl class.

```
interface TestDataSource {

    suspend fun setTestFlag(flag: Boolean)

    suspend fun getTestFlag(): Flow<Boolean?>
}

class TestDataSourceImpl : TestDataSource {

    private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "test")

     val context: Context by kInject()

    companion object {

        val testFlag= booleanPreferencesKey("testKey")
    }

    override suspend fun setTestFlag(flag: Boolean) {
        context.dataStore.edit {
            it[testFlag] = flag
        }
    }

    override suspend fun getTestFlag(): Flow<Boolean?> {
        return flow {
            emit(context.dataStore.data.map { value ->
                value[testFlag]
            }.first())
        }
    }
}
```

interface TestDataSource {

```
suspend fun setTestFlag(flag: Boolean)

suspend fun getTestFlag(): Flow<Boolean?>
```

}

class TestDataSourceImpl : TestDataSource {

```
private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "test")

 val context: Context by kInject()

companion object {

    val testFlag= booleanPreferencesKey("testKey")
}

override suspend fun setTestFlag(flag: Boolean) {
    context.dataStore.edit {
        it[testFlag] = flag
    }
}

override suspend fun getTestFlag(): Flow<Boolean?> {
    return flow {
        emit(context.dataStore.data.map { value ->
            value[testFlag]
        }.first())
    }
}
```

}